# how to create an array of unique items in an JSON response array?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I want to push the unique items in an array to an empty array from the below response which is
[image]

Here the title key is same for many items, I want to push the unique items to an empty array for which I have written the following function which is :

```
const getPendingList = (data) => {
    if (data) {
      var stack = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < data.length - 1; i++) {
        if (data[i + 1].title !== data[i].title) {
          stack.push(data[i].title);
        }
      }
      console.log('stack', stack);
      return stack.length;
    }
  };
```

But when I console stack here, I ain't getting the last unique item :
[image]

If I change the loop to

```
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
```

for some unknown reason am getting the following error:

[image]
could anyone please let me know where have I gone wrong? Any leads would be great, kindly let me know if anything else is required for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with this piece of code

```
for (let i = 0; i < data.length - 1; i++) {
    if (data[i + 1].title !== data[i].title) {
      stack.push(data[i].title);
    }
  }
```

Change `data.length - 1` to `data.length`.

Comment: have tried doing that but for some unknown reason I am getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined if I change it to data.length, would add the screenshot above you could check

Answer (score 0):

You get the error for the last element because you try to check the property on the next element of it, which does not exist ( as the current element is the last one). So just change your code to this and you should be fine:

```
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length - 1; i++) {
    if (data[i + 1] && data[i + 1].title !== data[i].title) {
      stack.push(data[i].title);
    }
  }
```